# Вывести элемент enum

Tags: c++

```
enum Type { A=1, B, C };
```

Если я запрашиваю через `cin>>` число, то как по этому числу вывести элемент перечисления?Например ввел 2, вывело B

В гугле искал, не нашел... все примеры для C#

Comment: В `С++` такое поведение не предусмотрено. Вы с таким же успехом могли бы спросить: "как напечатать имя переменной, адрес которой хранит указатель".

Comment: а никак, кроме как написать свою функцию для преобразования/вывода.

Некоторые изголяются, делая свои макросы для этого.

Comment: Можно сделать через `map`

Comment: ОК, я понял что простым способом этого не сделать, только через танцы с бубном :/

Comment: Так это ж С++, а не питон )))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Доброго времени суток! Ответ на Ваш вопрос зависит от того что вы хотите получить. Если вы хотите получить *имя* элемента перечисления, то Вам необходимо перегрузить операторы ввода/вывода в поток. Этот прием я узнал из книги Б. Страуструпа "Дизайн и эволюция С++" (очень советую почитать - можно много почерпнуть полезного). 
Если же вы хотите просто узнать сам элемент перечисления, то тогда используйте `static_cast` для безопасного приведения типов.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

enum Type { A = 0, B, C };

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const Type& t)
{
   switch(t) {
      case A: return (out << "A");
      case B: return (out << "B");
      case C: return (out << "C");
   }
   return (out);
}

std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& input, Type& t)
{
   std::string s;
   input >> s;
   if (s == "A") {
     // неявная конвертация в Type
     t = A;
   } else
   if (s == "B") {
     t = B;
   } else 
   if (s == "C") {
     t = C;
   } else {
     // здесь можно выкинуть исключение
     throw std::runtime_error("incorrect input");
   } 
   return (input);    
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   using namespace std;
   Type type;
   try {
     cin >> type;
   } catch(std::exception& e) {
     cout << e.what();
     return 1;
   }
   cout << type << "=" << static_cast<int>(type);
   return 0;
}
```

Вариант с ассоциативным массивом тоже имеет право на существование, но приходится платить перерасходом памяти, к тому же перечисления обычно меняются редко, так что вставить потом пару строк будет не сложно.

Answer (score 1):

Ну например можно было погуглить по запросу "c++ enum to string" 
и добрый Гугл выдал бы вам первым же результатом вот [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281461/enum-to-string-c)
 Немного нехитрых колдунств с вашей стороны, и все работает

Comment: Офигенный ответ. Отсылка к SO, где еще неочевидно, что правильно отвечают.

Comment: Ну почему, норм ответ... там всё такми много вариантов + заметил там ссылку на похожую тему, где тоже большое обсуждение. 
я просто писал в гугле различные варианты на русском, поэтому и не попал туда.

Comment: @Comfmore, в SO только один ответ (с мапом) правильный. В остальных неявно предполагается, что enum переменные, используемые как индексы имеют значения 0, 1, ... 

А это язык не гарантирует.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите для char *, аналогично для int

```
enum ex {A, B, C, NONE};
struct enex {
  ex    en;
  const char *name;
};

static ex
get_enum (const char *name)
{
  static struct enex en[] = {{A,"A"},{B,"B"},{C,"C"},{A,0}};
  for (int i = 0; en[i].name; i++)
    if (strcmp(name,en[i].name) == 0)
      return en[i].en;
  return NONE;
}
```

Comment: ну слишком мудрено, можно тогда уж проще в функции get_enum сделать switch и по цифре возвращать строку:

case 1: return "A";
и т.д.

Comment: Это, по сути, бессмысленно. Здесь ведь просто создается массив перечислений. Легче уж обычный массив использовать. Если уж возникла такая необходимость в "нумеровании" ENUM, то можно, к примеру, использовать ассоциативный контейнер Map<T> из STL или создать статический массив. Ну, или если элементов не так уж и много, то можно все их задать константами.

Comment: Возможно (увидев `cin >>`) я неправильно понял вопрос.

Я решил, что требуется по введенному числовому значению вернуть enum, но написал возвращение для введенного **имени**.

Вообще-то сравнение между enum и int компилятор (g++) разрешает, поэтому для числовых значений можно просто искать в массиве enum-ов введенное с клавиатуры целое и возвращать enum.

Но, это как-то некрасиво ("стремно").